# Multiple spring security configurations for formLogin and basic auth

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a web application with the standard form login authentication and I'm trying to add an api section secured with basic auth.

My security config file looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.antMatcher("/api/**")
              .httpBasic().and()
              .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
              .csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("test").password("pass").roles("USER")
                .and().withUser("test2").password("pass").roles("ADMIN");
        } 
    }


    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FormWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private LoginSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.csrf().disable();

            //loginSuccessHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/landing");
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                    .and()
                 //   .httpBasic().and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
                    // login success redirect handled by loginSuccessHandler
                    //.defaultSuccessUrl("/landing")
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .deleteCookies("remember-me")
                    .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                    //.logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .rememberMe();


        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        } 


        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                    "/**/*.css", "/**/*.png", "/**/*.gif", "/**/*.jpg", "/**/*.js","/**/*.map", "/fonts/*");
        }
    }



}
```

I'm testing with two urls: api/test and api/testSecured. Without the ApiWebSecurityConfig configuration, visiting api/test produces the expected response and api/testSecured redirects to the login page. WITH ApiWebSecurityConfig, however, both urls result in 404s. Why would this be? I was expecting the same content on api/test and 401 on api/testSecured

edit:

The logs show:

```
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2f3745b1
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/test'; against '/**/*.css'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/test'; against '/**/*.png'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/test'; against '/**/*.gif'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/test'; against '/**/*.jpg'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/test'; against '/**/*.js'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/test'; against '/**/*.map'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/test'; against '/fonts/*'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/test'; against '/api/**'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/test at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/test at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/test at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@71a60793
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/test at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/test'; against '/logout'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/test at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.517 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/test at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.518 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/test at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.518 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/test at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.518 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6fabe8e0: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe9938: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 3F32CE65028D5FCD8C8589AFA4D842AD; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.518 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/test at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.518 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/test at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.518 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/test at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-08-22 01:13:13.518 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/test; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2016-08-22 01:13:13.518 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6fabe8e0: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe9938: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 3F32CE65028D5FCD8C8589AFA4D842AD; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2016-08-22 01:13:13.518 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@36fb2af7, returned: -1
2016-08-22 01:13:13.520 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_51]

2016-08-22 01:13:13.520 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2016-08-22 01:13:13.520 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2016-08-22 01:13:13.520 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@37f512ab
2016-08-22 01:13:13.520 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-08-22 01:13:13.520 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2f3745b1
2016-08-22 01:13:13.521 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/401.html]
2016-08-22 01:13:13.521 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /401.html
2016-08-22 01:13:13.523 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/401.html]
2016-08-22 01:13:13.523 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Looking up handler method for path /401.html
2016-08-22 01:13:13.524 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Did not find handler method for [/401.html]
2016-08-22 01:13:13.524 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Looking up handler method for path /401.html
2016-08-22 01:13:13.529 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Did not find handler method for [/401.html]
2016-08-22 01:13:13.529 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/401.html] are [/**]
2016-08-22 01:13:13.529 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/401.html] are {}
2016-08-22 01:13:13.529 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/401.html] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@5bf7e3d3]]] and 1 interceptor
2016-08-22 01:13:13.529 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/401.html] is: -1
2016-08-22 01:13:13.530 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-08-22 01:13:13.530 DEBUG  --- [nio-1010-exec-2] .s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Also, commenting out the second configuration doesn't change anything for the api/.. requests, they still 404.

Comment: The log says "user is anonymous". How do you authenticate yourself?

Comment: @zeroflagL, initially I was sending `Authorization: user:pass` where user:pass is base64 encoded. I changed it to `Authorization: Basic user:pass` and it's working correctly now. Though, while testing through the browser, it'd be nice to have the application return a 401 and cause the browser to show the basic auth login instead of just giving a 404